# WPF: Using the ItemsControl DataTemplate in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, itemscontrol

I'm learning WPF and I'm trying to do something simple. I have two classes: `Candy` and `MyColor`. The code of these two classes look like this

```
public class Candy
{
    public MyColor Color { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyColor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Id { get; set; }
}
```

(I have attached an image below to make it clearer)

I have an area in the window in which I can create a `MyColor` by using a textbox that inserts the `MyColor.Name`, and a simple logic which increments the `MyColor.Id`. On the other side of the window, I have a button that creates new item in a ItemsControl which holds `Candy`. Within this `ItemsControl` there is an `ComboBox` which I can specify `Candy.Color` and a `TextBox` which I specify the `Candy.Name`. Finally, when I hit the button *Generate List* the code should output in the `TextBox` below a list in the format of

Candy.Color Candy.Name

[image: Color Candy Maker]

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically populate the `ComboBox` filled with a list of Colors I have created so I can specify the `Candy` color, but I don't know how to bind my data source. Also, how would I generate the text?

Currently my code looks like this

```
namespace QuestionToAsk
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<MyColor> Colors;
    ObservableCollection<Candy> Candies;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Colors = new ObservableCollection<MyColor>();
        Candies = new ObservableCollection<Candy>();

        Colors.Add(new MyColor() { Name = "(Unspecified)", Id = 0 });

        icColors.ItemsSource = Colors;
        icCandies.ItemsSource = Candies;
    }

    private void btnColor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtColor.Text != "")
        {
            uint last_id = Colors.Last<MyColor>().Id;
            Colors.Add(new MyColor() { Name = txtColor.Text, Id = last_id+1 });
            txtColor.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void btnNewCandy(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Candies.Add(new Candy());
    }

    private void btnGetList(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //How to create the list of <Color, Name>?
    }
}

public class Candy
{
    public MyColor Color { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyColor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Id { get; set; }
}
}
```

And my XML file looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="QuestionToAsk.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuestionToAsk"
        Title="Color Candy Maker" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Margin="3">
            <Button Content="Add Color" Click="btnColor" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtColor" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="icColors" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="tColorsTemplate">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Name="Color" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3">
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Content="New Candy" Click="btnNewCandy" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Button Content="Generate List" Click="btnGetList" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
            <ItemsControl Name="icCandies" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ComboBox Name="cmbColors" Grid.Column="0">
                               <!-- How to bind this cmbColors to icColors? -->
                            </ComboBox>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtColorCandy"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

I have removed all my ideas and implemented it using your hard design :D.

The xaml code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Margin="3">
        <Button Content="Add Color" Click="btnColor" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtColor" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="icColors" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="tColorsTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Name="Color" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="New Candy" Click="btnNewCandy" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Button Content="Generate List" Click="btnGetList" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="icCandies" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ComboBox Name="cmbColors" Grid.Column="0"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Colors, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Color}">
                        </ComboBox>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtColorCandy" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Note the usage of `RelativeSource` since the values of `ComboBox` was in a property of the `Window` class while the selected value was to be saved in the `Candy` class. So the `ItemsSource` is bound to a property of `Window` class and the `SelectedItem` is bound to a property of the `Candy` class

Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyColor> _colors;

    public IEnumerable<MyColor> Colors
    {
        get { return _colors; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Candy> _candies;

    public IEnumerable<Candy> Candies
    {
        get { return _candies; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _colors = new ObservableCollection<MyColor>();
        _candies = new ObservableCollection<Candy>();

        _colors.Add(new MyColor { Name = "(Unspecified)", Id = 0 });
        icColors.ItemsSource = Colors;
        icCandies.ItemsSource = Candies;
    }

    private void btnColor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtColor.Text != "")
        {
            uint last_id = Colors.Last<MyColor>().Id;
            _colors.Add(new MyColor() { Name = txtColor.Text, Id = last_id + 1 });
            txtColor.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void btnNewCandy(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _candies.Add(new Candy());
    }

    private void btnGetList(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in _candies)
        {
            if (item.Name == null || item.Color == null)
                continue;
            sb.AppendLine(item.Color.Name + " " + item.Name);
        }

        txtColorCandy.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

It there are any confusion let me know and I will try to help

Comment: Hi @sandesh, I noticed that the change you made wasn't really quite I wanted. I was hoping that when I click "New Candy" I could create a new Item in the ItemsControl on the top right of the window, so that I would be able to see each candy with each color.

Comment: Hi, I haven't been able to test the new one, but I was able to solve it myself. The solution is similar to what you have proposed. Thanks! :)